# Tracking Computers in an Online Game

Tags: php, javascript, anti-cheat

So i am running into a problem with people making multiple accounts to make there account better with more resource in game.

So my dilemma is, Many users go thru proxys or NATd info so some legimated users would be banned if i only have 1 user per ip.

Is there a way (with Javascript and PHP) to Get a uniq identifier specific to a computer (without Hardware changes, computer hardware change probably would change the identifier).

Any idea or comments would be much appericated

---

(The following was revived from a response made by Paul, but deleted by another for being out of place.)

I cant change the client to much because its a browser based game so getting the hwid would be possible. But how with JS or PHP.

Adding timers and restrictions to prevent transfers are in place but doesnt stop them entirely there is an option to email for an IP exception. but that is slow an tedious. Im wondering if there is a definitive to generate a specific id or identifier for a specific computer (Not ip based) that would make it so multiple accounts cant be logged in from the same computer but can be logged in from the same ip

Comment: in short no; there is no way to stop user setting up multiple accounts.

Comment: welcome to SO! Please don't use the answer section to add clarification. You can edit your question to add more details (you seem to be using two accounts, you might want to merge them and use one). Or you can add comments to answers to your questions (there is a rep requirement for this)

Comment: how ironic when he's asking about how to detect players using multiple accounts when he himself has multiple accounts on SO ... :P

Answer (score 1):

As we are talking about a different account, probably on a different IP and client, you cannot  easily find out clone accounts.

You can go for two more heuristic and gameplay options

1. As suggested before (by @dqhendricks), divide your resources and implement your sharing etc in such a way that you can't easily help your other account with every new account. Make finding other accounts in the beginning hard/impossible, make shareable resources a higher level feature etc. Downside is that this changes the gameplay, it doesn't have to be desireable.
2. You can perform heuristics on behaviour. There can be specific behaviour that is unwanted: only interaction with 1 other account etc. You could tweak some of the variables etc, but you could easily see suspicious behaviour. Make some sort of 'balance' calculation. Most ingame interactions have some sort of balance. Ofcourse, better players may have a good deal because they know more, or the other way around: they make a bad deal to help smaller players. But when one player only gives and never takes, it's "helping" without acutally playing itself: that might mean it's a clone

Everything with ip-adresses or client-information ($_SERVER) etc is worthless in this case as far as I'm concerned..

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent multiple logins on the same Account (username/password).

If the issue is that they make multiple accounts with many different email addresses etc... and new usernames and passwords then you might be able to do it with Cookies for example that use a unique hardware id and then you simple check that not more than one account is active at any one time based on this hwid. if the hardware changes it doesnt matter as it is relative.

To clarify if the HW id for the first login is 1234 then the second login with generate the same hwid. If you check the cookies or your database (doesnt matter where you store it) for the same hwid then you know its already logged in.

If the hardware changes it doesnt matter as they will still both generate the same hwid.

If they use two computers though the haardware id will be different and this will work.

Comment: How would you make a hardwareId in a web environment? Same computer, different IP (proxy) and different browser = indistinguishable  as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

{sharable resources} = {total resources} - MAX(({starting resources} - {spent resources}), 0)

make only non-starting resources sharable, or maybe make sharing resources an ability you don't gain until level x.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing spoofed/duplicate accounts (while ensuring all legitimate accounts work) is a very difficult task -- for reasons laid out by others. In addition to trying to guard against *concurrent* multiple accounts, one must guard against *non-concurrent* multiple account usage.

The core issue isn't so much in determining *where* an account connected from, but *being able to trust that a user only has one account* -- and to this end the only "real" solution is to use a system which already provides this sort of information, such as a credit card or paypal account ;-) That is, simply *prevent* someone from creating a new account (although an account can have multiple aliases/profiles, but these can be trivially tracked) unless they can prove "uniqueness".

(Also consider that two people may have two different accounts on the same machine.)

Happy coding.

Comment: It could be, but that would make it a bit harder to join the game :(

Comment: @Nanne Yes, it is not an ideal situation for a free game :-)

Comment: But, I agree, one of the only 100% solutions.

Answer (score -1):

I run an online game server aswell. To prevent your dilema, either modify the game client to read the MAC Address, and only allow 1 account per computer. Or log the ip's and only allow the resources to be given to that ip twice.
3rd option: Don't allow transfering of materials from the same ip addresses
4th option: Add a timer on the transfering of resources, make them wait 10 minutes of gameplay before they can do anything like getting rid of the items for others to get

Comment: yes it is, every computer has a mac address, you can always modify your client to view the mac address as long as you are able to modify the client you're using

Comment: The question is talking about an in-browser game. PHP will not help you here, this is SERVER side, and will not have the MAC-address available. It's also highly unlikely that you will be able to find it using javascript. If you would, i'd consider it a bug rather then a feature. So no, in the scenary the question describes you have NO mac-address that you can actually read. IP-based will not work, read the 2nd paragraph of the question.